# How to compare two versions

Tags: swift

I'm trying to compare two versions programs, but I cant input version bigger than Integer because .numeric take part of digit, I think - integer size, and compare. Please help me convert to another type in compare function or make other solution for comparison.

```
import Foundation

func versionFormatting(version:inout String) {
    version = String(version
        .unicodeScalars
        .filter(CharacterSet
        .decimalDigits
        .union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "."))
        .contains))
    if version[version.startIndex] == "."  {
        version.insert("0", at: version.startIndex)
    }
    if version[version.index(before: version.endIndex)] == "."  {
        version.insert("0", at: version.endIndex)
    }
    version = version.replacingOccurrences(of: "..", with: ".0.")
    version = version.replacingOccurrences(of: "..", with: ".0.")
}

func compareVersions(first: String, second: String) -> Int {
    let firstVersion = first.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let secondVersion = second.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let collectiveCount = min(firstVersion.count, secondVersion.count);
    for i in 0..<collectiveCount {
        if firstVersion[i].compare(secondVersion[i], options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return 0
        }
        else if secondVersion[i].compare(firstVersion[i], options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return 1
        }
    }
    let maxLengthArray: [String]
    let versionIndex: Int
    if firstVersion.count == collectiveCount {
        maxLengthArray = secondVersion
        versionIndex = 1
    }
    else {
        maxLengthArray = firstVersion
        versionIndex = 0
    }
    for i in collectiveCount..<maxLengthArray.count {
        if maxLengthArray[i].compare("0", options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return versionIndex
        }
    }
    return -1
}

//print ("First version: ")
//var firstVersion = readLine()!
var firstVersion = "1.0.0.0"
//print ("Second version: ")
//var secondVersion = readLine()!
var secondVersion = "1.0.0"

versionFormatting(version:&firstVersion)
versionFormatting(version:&secondVersion)

print(firstVersion)
print(secondVersion)

var result = compareVersions(first:firstVersion, second:secondVersion)
if result == -1 {
    print("версии равны")
}
else if result == 0 {
    print("первая версия актуальнее")
}
else {
    print("вторая версия актуальнее")
}
```

Comment: why not take them as string?

Comment: I agree, why can't you just compare on string to the other directly?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson I dont know how to do this on swift, maybe there is function for compare strings?

Comment: `if firstVersion > secondVersion {...`. For more info you should read up on the `Comparable` protocol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will address your needs.  I've changed it to an iterative method to make it a bit cleaner, and to use Floats not Ints.  If you're exceeding the limit of a Float you probably need to look at the problem not the solution :-)

I've also used an enum to return the result as it is more readable (though you can access the rawValue if you need your original return values.

```
enum Compared: Int {
   case v1Bigger = 1
   case v2Bigger = -1
   case equal = 0
}

func cleanAndSplit(_ version: String) -> [Float] {
   var cleaned = String(version.unicodeScalars.filter(CharacterSet.decimalDigits.union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: ".")).contains))
   guard !cleaned.isEmpty else {return []}
   if cleaned[cleaned.startIndex] == "."  {
       cleaned.insert("0", at: cleaned.startIndex)
   }
   if cleaned[cleaned.index(before: cleaned.endIndex)] == "."  {
       cleaned.insert("0", at: cleaned.endIndex)
   }
   cleaned = cleaned.replacingOccurrences(of: "..", with: ".0.")
   return cleaned.components(separatedBy: ".").compactMap{Float($0)}
}

func compare(_ v1: [Float], _ v2: [Float]) -> Compared  {
   guard !(v1.isEmpty && v2.isEmpty) else {return .equal}
   if v1.first! == v2.first! {
      return compare(Array(v1.dropFirst()), Array(v2.dropFirst()))
   }
   else  {
      return v1.first! > v2.first! ? .v1Bigger : .v2Bigger
   }
}

func compareVersionsStrings(_ version1: String, _ version2: String) -> Compared {
   var v1 = cleanAndSplit(version1)
   var v2 = cleanAndSplit(version2)
   let maxComponents = max(v1.count, v2.count)
   while v1.count < maxComponents { v1.append(Float(0))}
   while v2.count < maxComponents { v2.append(Float(0))}
   return compare(v1, v2)
}

let version1 = "21423542342342342365435.243543543645754687652"
let version2 = "21423542342342342365435.24354354364575468765"

let outcome  = compareVersionsStrings(version1, version2)
print(outcome)  //v1Bigger
```

I think this handles all the edge cases re unbalanced or invalid inputs, but it would be quite easy to adapt if you find any more.

Comment: in this case, if i input version1:0.0.0 and version2:0.0.0.0 this code doesnt work and say what version2 bigger

Comment: Good spot - missed that edge case (this is why unit tests are good ). I've updated the code to treat them as equal - technically they're not, but it's the most practical solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should use numeric comparison. For example, i wanna compare my iOS version with iOS 13 version.

```
let systemVersion = UIDevice.current.systemVersion
if systemVersion.compare("13.0", options: .numeric) != .orderedAscending { 
    // >= 13.0
}
```

Comment: for this example, i cant have version bigger than Integer size, if i have version 21423542342342342365435.24354354364575468765 this code doesnt work

Comment: @ДмитрийКононенко Maybe you should add some relevant examples to your question so we know what to deal with.

Comment: Some more context would help us provide better examples.  Your above example uses "1.0.0.0" which is very different to "21423542342342342365435.24354354364575468765". What are the possible range of inputs?

Comment: @flanker yes,my false. I need to improve function for work with version  21423542342342342365435.24354354364575468765 or bigger. Range must be bigger, than Integer

Comment: How many parts to your number?  4 as n the original example or 2 as above?  Also what will be used to separate the parts - will it always be a full stop? Finally do you just want to know if they are equal, or which is bigger, or the difference between them?

Comment: Sorry, i cant help, have no experience in comparing the numbers in long long string format like this.

Comment: @flanker u can see separation on my code where "separationBy". I can have random quantity parts. I need to understand which version is more actual( which is bigger).